# jQuery live search filter - Display 'Nothing Found' message and update WordPress post count

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, search, custom-post-type

I've got a WordPress post type called Employee Directory which lists employees of 3 different categories in 3 bxslider carousels - each post within an `li`. I have a single jQuery live search filter that searches all 3 categories. I've also got a query that counts how many posts of that type and category there are and I am needing the post count to update when the user types in the search bar.

I also need to display a message that says 'No Employees Found' when no results are returned.

**My JS within a document ready in my footer.php:**

```
// live search
  $('.live-search-list li').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-search-term', $(this).text().toLowerCase());
    });

    $('.live-search-box').on('keyup', function(){

    var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

        $('.live-search-list li').each(function(){

            if ($(this).filter('[data-search-term *= ' + searchTerm + ']').length > 0 || searchTerm.length < 1) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }

        });
    });
```

**My WordPress loop (there are 3 all the same except the category):**

```html
<div class="title-count">
  <h4>New Flyer</h4>
  <span>
<!-- Count number of posts in type and category -->
 <?php $args1 = array(
 'cat' => 2,
 'post_type' => 'employee-directory',
 );
 $the_query = new WP_Query( $args1 );
 echo $the_query->found_posts; ?> People
</span>
</div>
<!-- Loop through New Flyer Category -->
<ul class="carousel">
  <?php
$query1 = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type' => 'employee-directory',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'cat' => 2,
  'orderby' => 'title', 
  'order' => 'ASC'
    )
);
while ( $query1->have_posts() ) : $query1->the_post(); ?>
    <li class="nf">
      <a href="#" data-featherlight="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <div class="content-box">
          <div class="content-image">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail( 'staff', array('class' => 'img-fluid') );
    } else { ?>
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/placeholder_profile_photo.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
            <?php } ?>
          </div>
          <div class="content-info">
            <h5>
              <?php the_title(); ?>
            </h5>
            <p>
              <?php the_field('position'); ?>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
```

I know that I could combine my two queries into one, but because of the carousel, I need the loop to start inside the `ul` and the post count and category name to be outside of that loop, if that makes sense.

[Here is a link to that page on the dev site I'm working on.](https://apta.hatcherydev.xyz/employee-directory/)

I know that I could do this with some JS if statements but I'm not entirely sure how to implement that. Basically I need the WP Query and my JS to work together to count the posts, but don't know where to begin. Any help is hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of help from my colleague, I managed to get it working. Here's what we did:

Cleaned up my WP_queries by putting them all in the top of the document, followed by the loops:

```html
<?php
 $query1 = new WP_Query( array(
   'post_type' => 'employee-directory',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'cat' => 2,
   'orderby' => 'title', 
  'order' => 'ASC'
   )
 );
 $query1count = $query1->post_count;
 
 $query2 = new WP_Query( array(
   'post_type' => 'employee-directory',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'cat' => 3,
   'orderby' => 'title', 
   'order' => 'ASC'
   )
 );
 $query2count = $query2->post_count;

 $query3 = new WP_Query( array(
   'post_type' => 'employee-directory',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'cat' => 4,
   'orderby' => 'title', 
   'order' => 'ASC'
   )
 );
 $query3count = $query3->post_count;
<div class="title-count">
 <h4>New Flyer</h4>
 <span class="nf-count middle"><?php echo $query1count; ?></span> 
 <span>People</span> <span class="nf-message"></span>
 
</div>
<!-- Loop through New Flyer Category -->
 <ul class="carousel">  
 <?php while ( $query1->have_posts() ) : $query1->the_post(); ?>
  <li class="nf">
   <a href="#" data-featherlight="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <div class="content-box">
     <div class="content-image">
      <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
       the_post_thumbnail( 'staff', array('class' => 'img-fluid') );
       } else { ?>
       <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/placeholder_profile_photo.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
      <?php } ?>
     </div>
     <div class="content-info">
      <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
      <p><?php the_field('position'); ?></p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </a>
  </li>
 <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
 </ul>
```

Then we added classes to the `li` of each carousel slide and the `span` counts and referenced them in the new JS:

```js
$('.live-search-list li').each(function(){
 $(this).attr('data-search-term', $(this).text().toLowerCase());
 });
  
 $('.live-search-box').on('keyup', function(){
  
 var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
 var countNF = 0,
   countNFI = 0,
   countMCI = 0,
   totalItems = $('li').length,
   currentLoop = 0;
 
     $('.live-search-list li').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
       
         if ($this.filter('[data-search-term *= ' + searchTerm + ']').length > 0 || searchTerm.length < 1) {
             $this.show();
             // count different items
     if( $this.hasClass('nf') ) {
      countNF++;
      } else if( $this.hasClass('nfi') ) {
      countNFI++;
      } else {
      countMCI++;
      }
          } else {
              $this.hide();
          }
     currentLoop++;
       
    // last loop
     if( currentLoop == totalItems ) {
     $('.nf-count').text(countNF);
        $('.nfi-count').text(countNFI);
     $('.mci-count').text(countMCI);
     
               // do this for each category
     if( countNF > 0 ) {
     
          
     $('.nf-message').text('');
     } else {
     $('.nf-message').text('No employees found!');
     }
     if( countNFI > 0 ) {
     
     $('.nfi-message').text('');
     } else {
     $('.nfi-message').text('No employees found!');
     }
     if( countMCI > 0 ) {
          
     $('.mci-message').text('');
     } else {
     $('.mci-message').text('No employees found!');
     }
    }
   });
   });
```

This updates the post count and displays a 'No Employees Found' message as the user types in the search box.